# Recursive Binary Search of String Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I've created a binary search for a String array which is supposed to take two arguments, a word to find, and the array that it is scanning. I've been looking at my code for days, trying different things to figure out what to do, but so far I haven't been able to make the code work. I either get a `NullPointerException` or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Here is what I have so far.

```
public int recSearch(String[] words, String wordToFind)throws ItemNotFoundException {
    int start = 0;
    int end = words.length - 1;
    int mid = (start + end) /2;
    if(end < start) {
        return -1;
    } else if (words[mid].equals(wordToFind)) {
        incrementCount();
        return mid;
    } else if(words[mid].compareTo(wordToFind) < 0) {
        String[] split = new String[mid - 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            split[i] = words[i];
        }
        return recSearch(split,wordToFind);
    } else if(words[mid].compareTo(wordToFind) > 0) {
        String[] split = new String[mid - 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < mid -1; i++) {
            split[i] = words[i];
        }
        return recSearch(split,wordToFind);
    }
    return -1;
    // throw new ItemNotFoundException();
}
```

Comment: I'm asking just to be sure - are you passing sorted array to the function above?

Comment: You will mostly get 1 or 2 as result. two of your return statements are wrong. `return recSearch(split,wordToFind);` should be replaced by `return recSearch(split,wordToFind) + start;`

Comment: Yes, it is a sorted array.

Comment: adding + start did not work, still getting exceptions

Answer (score 0):

For implementing the binary search you can use the [Collections](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html) class for searching the element using [binary search](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.lang.Comparable%3C?%20super%20T%3E%3E,%20T)).
Simply you can search by using

```
Collections.binarySearch(List,Object)
```

here you replace the whole method with

```
`int index=    Collections.binarySearch(Arrays.toString(words),` "search_key");
```

Comment: The op didn't ask for out of the box solution and therefore this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have coded it wrongly in this part of the code:

```
else if(words[mid].compareTo(wordToFind) < 0){
    String[] split = new String[mid - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++){
        split[i] = words[i];
    }
    return recSearch(split,wordToFind);
}
else if(words[mid].compareTo(wordToFind) > 0)
{
    String[] split = new String[mid - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < mid -1; i++){
        split[i] = words[i];
    }
    return recSearch(split,wordToFind);
}
```

In the first `else if` array should be of size `mid` to accomodate values from `0` to `mid-1`. In the second `else if`, what you would be filling is `words[i+ mid+1] in words[i]`.

Comment: When i adjust it as so, every output i get it is -1 because end < start

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in a way you were splitting arrays. I corrected it below.
Please compare the code, you will understand what was going wrong (adding output helps a lot in such situations)

```
public int recSearch(String[] words, String wordToFind) throws ItemNotFoundException {
    int start = 0;
    int end = words.length;
    int mid = end / 2;

    if(end < start){
        return -1;
    } else if(wordToFind.equals(words[mid])) {
        incrementCount();
        return mid;
    } else if(wordToFind.compareTo(words[mid]) < 0) {
        String[] split = new String[mid];
        for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++){
            split[i] = words[i];
        }
        return recSearch(split,wordToFind);
    } else {
        String[] split = new String[end - mid - 1];

        for(int i = 0; i < end - mid - 1; i++){
            split[i] = words[mid + i + 1];
        }
        return recSearch(split, wordToFind);
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: please provide me with an example array and I will try to see where the issue lies ;-)